# How to position UIPopoverArrowDirection to TOP RIGHT of the popover view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button and when I click that a popover view appears. The arrow mark appears in the top centre of the screen as seen in the image.

[image: popover screen image]

```
@IBAction func notifyBtnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    var vieww: notificationViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popover") as! notificationViewController
    vieww.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    vieww.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 602)
    var vvv = vieww.popoverPresentationController
    vvv?.delegate = self
    vvv?.sourceView = self.view
    vvv?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 700, y: -510, width: 320, height: 602)
    vvv?.permittedArrowDirections = [.Up]        
    presentViewController(vieww, animated: true, completion: nil)       
}
```

But how to place the arrow mark in the TOP RIGHT of the popover view ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not built into UIKit, only the directions defined in the `UIPopoverArrowDirection` enum are supported.

If you define your own view (and popover controller) subclasses, you may be able to define such behavior by explicitly drawing a triangle where you want.